# Scala - how to pattern match when chaining two implicit conversions?

Tags: java, scala, collections, pattern-matching

I wrote a method to parse Metrics data and at first faced a problem with the type of transactionMap which is a `java.util.Map`. And I solved it using JavaConverters.

```
def parseMetrics(metric: Metric) = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    metric.transactionMap.asScala.values.map {
      case false => "N" 
      case true => "Y"
    }.toList
```

But after that I got an error while pattern matching true and false values: `pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found: Boolean, required: java.lang.Boolean`

As far as I understand Scala does not chain two implicit conversions. Is there a way to fix it using JavaConverters?

Comment: Can you change the match statement to `x => if (x) "Y" else "N"` ?

Comment: @AndyHayden It worked, thanks! Could you please tell why did this help to solve the problem? I guess that it's because we're not implicitly declaring true and false values, but not quite sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use if/else rather than a match statement for Boolean checking:

```scala
def parseMetrics(metric: Metric) = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    metric.transactionMap.asScala.values.map {
      x => if (x) "Y" else "N"
    }.toList
```

My suspicion is that within the if statement the `java.lang.Boolean` (which I presume `x` is here) can be coerced to `Boolean` via `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`... but the match statement doesn't do the same coercion, but would have to be made explicitly (or match on the `java.lang.Boolean` values).

Comment: `JavaConverters` aren't needed to convert `java.lang.Boolean` to `scala.Boolean`.

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround but it doesn’t really answer the question and your suspicion is incorrect. :)

Comment: @TravisBrown I'd read in the docs when writing this that an if statement had to be scala Boolean (but of course I can no longer find the reference), which suggested to me the coersion was required... Interesting.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer provides a reasonable way to solve this problem, but doesn't show why you're running into it or how the approach it proposes works.

The Scala standard library does provide an implicit conversion from `java.lang.Boolean` to `scala.Boolean`, which you can see in action by using `reify` in a REPL to desugar some code that uses a Java boolean in a context where a Scala boolean is expected:

```
scala> val x: java.lang.Boolean = true
x: Boolean = true

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> reify(if (x) 1 else 0)
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Int] =
Expr[Int](if (Predef.Boolean2boolean($read.x))
  1
else
  0)
```

The problem is that simply trying to match a `java.lang.Boolean` value against `true` or `false` isn't sufficient to trigger the conversion. You can check this by defining your own types where you can be sure you know exactly what conversions are in play:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int); case class Bar(i: Int)
defined class Foo
defined class Bar

scala> implicit def foo2bar(foo: Foo): Bar = Bar(foo.i)
foo2bar: (foo: Foo)Bar

scala> Foo(100) match { case Bar(x) => x }
<console>:17: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Bar
 required: Foo
       Foo(100) match { case Bar(x) => x }
                             ^
```

This is a language design decision. It would probably be possible to have the implicit conversions applied in these scenarios, but there's also probably a good reason that they aren't (off the top of my head I'm not familiar with any relevant discussions or issues, but that doesn't mean they don't exist).

The reason Andy's solution works is that the `java.lang.Boolean` is in a position where the compiler expects a `scala.Boolean` (a condition) and is willing to apply the `Predef.Boolean2boolean` conversion. You could do this manually if you really wanted to:

```
def parseMetrics(metric: Metric) = {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  metric.transactionMap.asScala.values.map(Predef.Boolean2boolean).map {
    case false => "N" 
    case true => "Y"
  }.toList
}
```

…but to my eye at least pattern matching on `Boolean` is a little clunkier than using a conditional.