# Scala - unreachable code when pattern matching Boolean values and a default

Tags: java, scala, collections, pattern-matching

I have a `Map[String, Boolean]` with various Metrics data and a separate `Seq[String]` containing `metricKeys`.

The problem is that the Map may not contain all the `metricKeys` but I need to keep the information about non-existing values as well. 
I've tried to solve this by using `.getOrElse`. I expected that the resulting `List[String]` with metric values will contain "Y" for `true`, "N" for `false` and "" for `null` values.

However I get a warning: `unreachable code case _ => StringUtils.EMPTY`. 
What would be the right way to get default values also matched correctly?

```
def parseMetrics(metric: Metric): List[String] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val metricKeys: Seq[String] = getMetricKeys
    val matricsData = metric.transactionMap.asScala

metricKeys.map(key => key -> matricsData.getOrElse(key, null))
      .toMap.values.map(Predef.Boolean2boolean).collect  {
      case true => "Y"
      case false => "N"
      case _ => StringUtils.EMPTY
    }.toList
}
```

Comment: what third value do you think there is for a boolean?

Comment: true and false are the only two values a Boolean can ever be. If you're doing a match on a Boolean, trying to have any cases which aren't true or false will throw this warning. Also, you shouldn't be using `null` in Scala.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54856780/334519) and `matricsData` has a type like `Map[String, java.lang.Boolean]`?

The issue then is that the `Predef.Boolean2boolean` conversion from boxed Java booleans to Scala booleans returns `false` when its argument is `null`, so if you want to distinguish between true, false, and `null` values of `java.lang.Boolean`, you'll need to do it before the conversion (whether or not that conversion is explicit, as it is here).

There are far better ways to approach this, though, like the following:

```
metricKeys.map { key =>
  matricsData.get(key) match {
    case Some(value) => if (value) "Y" else "N"
    case None        => StringUtils.EMPTY
  }
}
```

Or use `fold` on `Option` instead of pattern matching:

```
metricKeys.map { key =>
  matricsData.get(key).fold(StringUtils.EMPTY) { value =>
    if (value) "Y" else "N"
  }
}
```

Or transform the map values first and then look up all your keys:

```
val asYN: Map[String, String] = matricsData.mapValues { value =>
  if (value) "Y" else "N"
}

metricKeys.map(key => asYN.getOrElse(key, StringUtils.EMPTY))
```

Which approach you choose is a matter of taste, but any of these are better than using boxed Java booleans to model some kind of three-way true-or-false-or-missing data.

Answer (score -1):

Just use map.get, which will return Option[Boolean], 
and then case on Some(true), Some(false) and None